# Google Sheet Script - save each tab into seperate file in specific folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google sheet with multiple tabs and I need to save each tab into a new file in a specific folder. The below code works but it saves everything in the root My Drive folder. How do I specify the folder where the new file should be created?

```
function copySheetsToSS() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  for(var n in ss.getSheets()){
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[n];// look at every sheet in spreadsheet
    var name = sheet.getName();//get name
    if(name != 'CSD' && name !='HES' && name != 'NHM' && name != 'NUR' && name != 'RMPE' && name != 'S W' && name != 'Validations'){ // exclude some names
      var alreadyExist = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);// check if already there
      while(alreadyExist.hasNext()){
        alreadyExist.next().setTrashed(true);// delete all files with this name
      }
      var copy = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);// create the copy
      sheet.copyTo(copy);// copy content
      copy.getSheets()[0].setName(name);// rename first sheet to same name as SS
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move to the right folder after creating the new file

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("___here the ID of your folder___")
var copy = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);// create the copy
sheet.copyTo(copy);// copy content
DriveApp.getFileById(copy.getId()).moveTo(folder);// move to folder
```